# Deploy multiple Web services versions at same domain

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, deployment

I would like to have all my Web services versions deployed at the same domain, like this:

- rest.mydomain.com/v1/
- rest.mydomain.com/v2/
- ...

But these different versions are in different servers. Do I need to use a load balance server to configure this behavior? Or is there a better way to to that?

Answer (score 2):

Load Balancing is the best option. Nginx, haproxy, apache, etc. support load balancing / reverse proxy based on the url path.

[Layer 7 Load Balancing with HAproxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-as-a-layer-7-load-balancer-for-wordpress-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Reverse Proxy with Nginx](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: HD, and all the requests will pass through the load balancer, or just the first?

Comment: All requests will pass through it.

Comment: Performance problems?

Comment: Can't see performance problems unless that the latency between the Load Balancers and the backend servers is high (different networks). CPU / Memory usage on LBs is very low . All the requests will pass through the LB so you'll need the combined bandwidth from all your backends in the LB.

Comment: Always same network. Got it!